# aws sns sms usage reports, able to save message body?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I now that we can set up SNS service SMS subscription which would save the `MessageId` and few other info.

At first, I thought it would also save the messages too but while reading the records, it is not included.

Is there a way to include it or it's just something we have to do manually while sending the sms?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message content is not part of your delivery receipt metadata, so it's a good practice that you do your own book-keeping and track all the messages you've sent. A sample schema could be something like:

> Destination Phone Number (e.g. +12065551234)
>
> ISO Country Code (e.g. US)
>
> Sent Date (epoch)
>
> Message Id (auto-generated from request)
>
> MCCMNC carrier information
>
> Message Content

Then you can store all this data in a data storage of your choice.

An example architecture (that is cost efficient for high traffic) could be:

- Create metadata POJO and serialize into JSON
- Use Kinesis Firehose to stream/batch your serialized metadata into S3
- Use AWS Glue to determine the schema of your S3 objects
- Use AWS Athena to query your stored S3 data

You can read the documentation on how to setup CloudWatch to store metrics and logs for SMS deliveries [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html)

Another recommendation is to check your SMS usage reports. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_usage.html) is the documentation for that.

Best of luck.

*Disclosure*: I work in AWS and I worked in the Mobile Messaging (SMS/Push) team.

Comment: nice, thanks for the response.  I did got the SMS usage reports setup.  I guess for now that should do it and saving some data into my data storage such as message content, id, and date which would be quite enough already if I really do have to find info about the message record which might not even happen but just thinking of the possible choices.  I will definitely try the CloudWatch way in the future for my own learning purpose.  Thanks a lot

Comment: P.S. It would be a good idea to noted in the SMS usage reports that it might take a day or two in order to see the report as it's not mentioned there :(

Comment: @Dora thanks for the feedback! And yes, the usage reports might take up to 3 days because that's the nature of SMS. These messages are delivered through carriers on a "best effort" basis. Sometimes, destination phone numbers might be out of network reach; a delivery receipt will only be final once the message either fails or reaches its destination. Happy coding!